# Proper way to echo quoted text inside html

Tags: php, html, escaping, quote

I'm storing text in database like "He can't ...". But when I echo this text, as it is inside HTML markup, browser get's `'` as closing of some html element's markup. Which PHP function to use before, to echo safely this type of text inside html markup?

Comment: HTML markup uses tags like `<p>` and `</p>` as the brackets of markup. How would a quote end something like this? Are you talking about an attribute value, like `value='$text`'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`htmlentities()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo "<input type='text' value='" . htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401) . "'>";
```

The `ENT_QUOTES` flag tells it to convert both single and double quotes to entities (the default is just double quotes).